# Firewall (iptables) settings after changing Azure Ubuntu-based VM size

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I use Azure virtual machines, and recently scaled up the VM size to DS14. My question is: during this scale up, the VM was restarted. Would my firewall set up in `iptables` from the previous machine have carried over to the new machine? I unfortunately didn't keep a backup of that, so need to be sure either way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would my firewall set up in iptables from the previous machine have
>   carried over to the new machine?

**Resize your VM to a larger or smaller size will not change your VM's configuration.**  Resize VM only changes the size of your VM based on the needs for CPU, Network or disk performance. More information please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/).

So, the iptables will carry over to the new machine.

Notes: You should save your iptables rule to `/etc/iptables.rules`. If you don't save them, when you restart your VM, the rules will lose. However, it is no related with resizing VM size.